# React Native failing to compile due to 'ASCII' error in build.gradle

Tags: reactjs, gradle, ascii, native, yarnpkg

I've been using React Native for about a year now and have been enjoying it until I got this really annoying error that I have spent days trying to figure out what is causing it. This has been happening since we added Firebase to our app.

It runs fine on iOS, but on Android it is completely broken. Here is what happens when I run yarn against my project.

```
yarn run v1.9.4
warning package.json: "dependencies" has dependency "react-native-social-share" with range "^1.6.3" that collides with a dependency in "devDependencies" of the same name with version "^1.0.0"
$ react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\MyReactProject\node_modules (23ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\MyReactProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII
```

The problem above was due to this line in my build.gradle.

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'
```

so I updated it to the following and that fixed the ASCII problem

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

However when I update that I get even more problems, mostly Duplicate Class errors between Android.Support and AndroidX and the app will just not run.

I thought the "plus sign" when declaring dependencies was perfectly valid in React Native but my compiler just doesn't like it.

Does anyone have an idea on what might be happening? any help will be much appreciated, why won't my compiler accept the + sign?

Here is my build.gradle from the project root

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

/**
 Project-wide Gradle configuration properties
 */
ext {
    compileSdkVersion   = 26
    targetSdkVersion    = 26
    buildToolsVersion   = "26.0.3"
    supportLibVersion   = "26.1.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
}
```

and my build.gradle from the app side.

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ionic.MyReactProject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 7006
        versionName "2.05"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }

    subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate {
        if ((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    // To check for a certain build type, use variant.buildType.name == "<buildType>"
                    if (names.contains("reactNative51") || names.contains("reactNative55")) {
                        // Gradle ignores any variants that satisfy the conditions above.
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-branch')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
      compile project(':react-native-social-share')
  compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-fast-image')
    compile project(':react-native-navigation')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')

    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: This has been resolved, we had to downgrade Firebase and upgrade Gradle.